# I have a c:set variable in Java. I want to +1 to the value in a rich:dataTable, is this possible?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jstl, jsf-1.2

I have a c:set variable in Java. I want to +1 to the value in a `rich:dataTable`, is this possible?

```
    <h:form id="webstoreSettings" styleClass="edit">
        <c:set var="_count" value="0" scope="page" />
        <rich:panel>
            <rich:simpleTogglePanel label="Store Properties"
                switchType="client" rendered="true">
                <div style="margin: 7px 0px;">
                    <rich:dataTable id="webListsTable"
                        value="#{storeHome.webPropertiesVars}" var="_var">
                        <h:column id="webstoreVarCol">
                            <h:outputLabel id="webstoreVar_#{_count}" value="#{_var.webstoreVar}" />
                            <c:set var="_count" value="#{_count + 1}" scope="page" />
                        </h:column>
                    </rich:dataTable>
                </div>
            </rich:simpleTogglePanel>
        </rich:panel>
    </h:form>
```

All of the id="webstoreVar_0" are the same :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. JSTL tags run during view build time, not during view render time. The `<rich:dataTable var>` is only available during view render time.

I'm not sure why exactly you need a `<h:outputLabel id>` like that. It makes no sense. Just remove the EL from the `id` attribute. JSF will already prepend it with the row index of the data table.

```html
<h:outputLabel id="webstoreVar" ... />
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: I WISH we had JSF2... it is JSF 1.2.. one of those situations where they threw down the architecture with absolutely no plan to upgrade with new releases.